# How to map domain model object to its http representation?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a Post domain model object with the `title`, `body`, and `author` attributes. It is persisted in a datatable with the `id`, `title`, `body` and `author_id` columns. I have left the ID fields out from its domain object because these fields seem like a persistence concern, not something that my domain object needs to be aware of.

The issue that I am having is that when I want to return a Post instance in a http response as a JSON object, I want to include the `id` and `author_id` fields. How should I retrieve these fields from the domain object? More generally, I would like to know if there are good ways to handle the mapping from a domain object to other representations.

Comment: ID and authorID are not persistence concerns: your object model also needs IDs to identify entities and references to link them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should distinguish between "entity" and "value" types.

Here Post is an entity, because you have a whole bunch of them and they are indistinguishable without an id.

ie, you could have duplicates, or edit an instance but still want to know that the dupes are different posts and the edited post is the same post as its pre edit version.

For entities the Id is part of the domain object. Most things are entities and its just easy to include the id to solve most issues.

Avoid using a database generated id to keep your separation of concerns.

Value objects are things like "Month" or "Currency" theres only one "January", € etc they don't need ids, as the value is the id.

There are edge cases, for example say I want to display the country of birth of each author of each post. Country is a value type and doesn't have an id, and even if i change it to an entity its not going to have a PostId property.

Here you can return a Map or Dictionary or list of tuples etc with the postId and country data linked in one of these generic data structures.

This avoids the problem of returning huge trees of Post.Author.Address.Country or making lookup calls in loops

Comment: Thanks. Am I right to say that two mappers will be required? One for mapping between its database and entity representations. Another for mapping between its entity and http response representations?

Comment: ermmm....  your domain object should be the thing you pass around I wouldn't map it to a DTO or ViewModel for no reason. But I would need to see more of your code/frameworks used etc